# Laravel Api : Slow Data Fetch

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle, slowapi

First of all, I want to make a system that instantly pulls some data using Laravel. For example: Think of it like Coin Prices. I want to fetch the values of 20 different coins from 5 different exchanges on every page refresh. Actually, I don't have a problem with this. My exact problem. Very Slow Receiving Data from API. Normally, the Api resource given to me opens in a short time, but while I try to pull every data, I make a query again. And it runs 5*20 100 queries on each page refresh. And Because of That I'm Getting Both Slow and Error. How Can I Solve This.
So I want to take the data once and fill the table over it. I don't want to pull over and over for every transaction. I hope I was able to explain my problem. Thank you in advance for your interest and concern.

The Class I'm Using Is " Illuminate\Http\Request;"

[View Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAdUX.png)

I TryI Couldn't Do Anything About It. Sends Multiple Requests to the Same Address Every Time

---

Edit

The mistake I made: by writing a helper, it was reading data from the api for each data, for each point, briefly for everything. Instead of doing it directly on the blade page, I defined it in my controller and directed it to the blade page and because it calls each data once, my problem was solved, thank you everyone.

Comment: If you are fetching data from table that has relationships with other table, make sure to adopt eagre loading and pagination for faster queries
**eagre loading** https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
**pagination**  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#basic-usage

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  So how can I use this with guzzle/http.  So I am pulling api from an External Source.

Comment: Welcome to SO, would you update your question and bring pictured code and post straight into your question?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would take all data that is not related to the display, out of the blade and put maybe in the controller/service/model depends what it does.

Second thing, you should try to load some data with [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) so you don't pull all data separately each time (if you are getting something from the database).

If you have API with a lot of JSON objects then you could take it all, [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#chunking-results), and then check if that result exists in the table, take the next one, and if not, store it.